# Respawn destroyed object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, destroy

I have this script where as to when i hit a trigger my enemy spawns at a random time then the enemy destroy itself at a random time. I want to respawn the enemy again so it can do this over and over again. Any Suggestions:

```
public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Enemy; // the enemy prefab
public float mytimer; // the time to wait before spawn
public float transport;// the time it has to destroy itself

private GameObject _spawndEnemy; // the enemy that was spawnd

void SpawnEnemy()
{
    var enemySpawnPoint =  GameObject.Find("FFEnemySpawn1").transform;
    _spawndEnemy = Instantiate(
         Enemy, enemySpawnPoint.position, enemySpawnPoint.rotation) as GameObject;
    transport = Random.Range (2,15);
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "FFTrigger") {
        mytimer = Random.Range(0,15);
        Invoke("SpawnEnemy", mytimer);
        Debug.Log("Spawn Normal");
    }
}

void Update()
{
    Destroy (_spawndEnemy, transport);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Ghostdre, this question is probably better suited to the Game Development SO site, as for making multiple enemies spawn, I would create an `Enemy` class and then hold an array or list of `Enemy`'s that live for a random amount of time in your `SpawnManager` class

Comment: Thanks Matthew and I was thinking array but I don't know how to set that up. But I will ask in the Game Development site.

Comment: @Ghostdre are you trying to make a parallax scrolling sort of a game?

Comment: Nope its a fps 3d horror game, but I think I found out how to do it. I just use the Invoke method again inside the SpawnEnemy. But I might have a problem in that the enemy should only spawn once, but instead it spawns multiple times.

Comment: Enemy is your prefab, so try to make instance of Enemy instead of GameObject. You can handle instance as GameObject later and do not use Destroy in Update as you can use it at the end of SpawnEnemy() method

`public Enemy enemy;`
`enemy.gameObject......`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ghostdre this question would probably be better answered here [Game Dev SO](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), as for your question I would recommend creating an `Enemy` class object and data members for the GameObject as well as a time variable which determines how long the Enemy should live before being Destroyed.

e.g.

```
public class SpawnManager
{
    public float lifeTime;

    ...

    void Update()
    {
        lifeTime -= Time.deltaTime

        if (lifeTime <= 0)
        {
            Destroy (_spawndEnemy, transport);
            SpawnEnemy()
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this is an incomplete example, but it should give you an idea of where to go from here.

Comment: So making the array public Enemy enemy = new List<enemy> will respawn the enemy again?

Comment: it depends on how you want it to function, do you want it to be able to spawn multiple enemies from the same spawn? or do you want one spawn to create one enemy at any given time?

Comment: Just one enemy spawning at one spawn. But if the enemy destroys itself I want the enemy to respawn itself back at the spawn.

Comment: I have edited my example, where I have the ... is where your existing code goes, you will need to set some value for lifeTime in your `SpawnEnemy()` method (if you want a random number than use `Random.Range(minVal, maxVal)`

Comment: further to this you should aim to better break up your functionality in this program (e.g having an enemy class to hold the gameobject, lifespan etc) otherwise your code will become very unwieldy very quickly